# calling function with a another function/ calculated value as a argument

Tags: html, angular, ng-bootstrap

Is it possible to call a function while passing the another function as a parameter in Angular 6?

Like this: 
**{{filterData({{split(object[key]}})[0])}}**

```
              <div>

              <ng-template #popContent >
                <div class="popover" >{{filterData({{split(object[key]}})[0])}}
                <button class="close" (click)="p.close()">X</button>
                </div>
              </ng-template>

            <button class="popoverLink" [ngbPopover]="popContent" [autoClose]="false"
                    triggers="manual" #p="ngbPopover" (click)="p.open()" placement="top-left" container="body">
              {{split(object[key])[0]}}
            </button>

              /{{split(object[key])[1]}}

            </div>
```

Comment: Remove the curly braces inside the `filterData` and try again it should work 
ex: `{{ filterData( split(object[key])[0] ) }}`

Comment: Also consider using pipes or precalculate result from this function call to avoid calling it more than required on page redraws